# Clean Code for If Statement

Tags: scala, if-statement, logic

I have a statement like this, how can i optimize this logic. I think about 1 hour but i dont find.

How can i simplfy this logic ?

```
if (model.WaitingChecked) 
{
    if (model.selectedStatus != 0) 
    {
        model.DataList = data.Where(x => x.status != 6 && x.status == model.selectedStatus);
        return View(model);
    }

    model.DataList = data.Where(x => x.status != 6);
    return View(model);
}

if (model.SelectedStatus != 0) 
{
    model.DataList = data.Cast<DataDetailedList>().Where(x => x.status == model.selectedStatus);
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: what does this do model.WaitingChecked?

Comment: I don't see any way to really simplify here, unless you can somehow combine conditions.  A Scala expert might have more to say.

Comment: I mean i have to use 3 times return view(model). It seems not optimized. @Pirate it is a checkbox on the view.

Comment: It rather look like imperative Java (!! `;` and `return`)

Comment: @cchantep I'd say, C#

Comment: @cchantep yes c#

Comment: why is this tagged with scala?

Comment: I dont know. I did not do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use pattern matching over the different conditions. Remember though pattern matching needs to be exhaustive. Meaning every combinations of the values needs to be defined.

```
(model.WaitingChecked, model.selectedStatus ) match{
  case (true, 0) =>
    model.DataList = data.Where(x => x.status != 6)
    View(model)
  case (true, _) =>
    model.DataList = data.Where(x => x.status != 6 && x.status == model.selectedStatus)
    View(model)
  case (_, 0) =>
    //missing logic for model.selectedStatus is zero return
  case (_, _) =>
    model.DataList = data.Cast<DataDetailedList>().Where(x => x.status == model.selectedStatus)
    View(model)
}
```

Comment: Also makes sense for `model.selectedStatus` to be an ADT -- so compiler will check for exhaustiveness.